# How to set up a local DBpedia mirror

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, java, dbpedia

I am trying to set up a local DBpedia Information Extraction Framework, but there seems to have some problems which I cannot deal with. I followed the instructions on the official site using Intelli J, it went well until I get to the final step that tells "select DBpedia dump extraction ->Plugins -> scala ->scala:run", the error message shows below:

```
    D:\program\jdk\bin\java -Dmaven.home=D:\program\apache-maven-3.0.5 -Dclassworlds.conf=D:\program\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin\m2.conf -Didea.launcher.port=7534 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=D:\program\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 12.1.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "D:\program\apache-maven-3.0.5\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar;D:\program\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 12.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher --fail-fast --strict-checksums org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2:run
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building DBpedia Dump Extraction 3.8
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] >>> maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2:run (default-cli) @ dump >>>
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ dump ---
    [debug] execute contextualize
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory E:\code\Scala\extraction_framework\dump\src\main\resources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2:compile (process-resources) @ dump ---
    [INFO] Checking for multiple versions of scala
    [INFO] includes = [**/*.scala,**/*.java,]
    [INFO] excludes = []
    [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ dump ---
    [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2:compile (compile) @ dump ---
    [INFO] Checking for multiple versions of scala
    [INFO] includes = [**/*.scala,**/*.java,]
    [INFO] excludes = []
    [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ dump ---
    [debug] execute contextualize
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory E:\code\Scala\extraction_framework\dump\src\test\resources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ dump ---
    [INFO] No sources to compile
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2:testCompile (test-compile) @ dump ---
    [INFO] Checking for multiple versions of scala
    [INFO] includes = [**/*.scala,**/*.java,]
    [INFO] excludes = []
    [WARNING] No source files found.
    [INFO] 
    [INFO]  org.dbpedia.extraction.dump.sql.Import
    parsing \home\release\wikipedia\wikipedias.csv
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org_scala_tools_maven_executions.MainHelper.runMain(MainHelper.java:161)
        at org_scala_tools_maven_executions.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:26)
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \home\release\wikipedia\wikipedias.csv (ϵͳ�Ҳ���ָ����·����)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:91)
        at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:76)
        at org.dbpedia.extraction.util.WikiInfo$.fromFile(WikiInfo.scala:26)
        at org.dbpedia.extraction.util.ConfigUtils$.parseLanguages(ConfigUtils.scala:43)
        at org.dbpedia.extraction.dump.sql.Import$.main(Import.scala:26)
        at org.dbpedia.extraction.dump.sql.Import.main(Import.scala)
        ... 6 more
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 2.104s
    [INFO] Finished at: Fri May 24 18:34:48 CST 2013
    [INFO] Final Memory: 10M/175M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2:run (default-cli) on project dump: wrap: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: -10000(Exit value: -10000) -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

what should I do to fix it?

PS: I did it all on windows 7 OS, with intelli j 12 community version, maven 3 and jdk 7 installed. If any other info is needed, please let me know, thanks.

Comment: The error reason is that `\home\release\wikipedia\wikipedias.csv` doesn't exists. This is [pretty googleable problem](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/18153/dbpedia-38-extraction-missing-wikipediascsv/18708).

Comment: thanks for your answer, and I have already got the message, but here is the problem, I built the framework on windows 7 OS, there is no way I could locate a file under such a directory like "\home\release...", should you have any solutions, it would be very nice if you tell me, thanks again.

Comment: Does anyone found a fix for this problem? @kuixiong Did you fixed it eventually?

Comment: Sorry, but I finally moved it to the linux OS and worked fine~